# Spark Scala: How to remove double quotes around each line, including headers?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm a beginning with Spark and the file I need to parse has this shape:

```
"VARIABLE;MOD;LIBMOD"
"CDEXE;6;PBS between 25000 and 50000 euros"
```

How to have a Dataset[ValueDescriptor] out of it?

A ValueDescriptor being:

`case class ValueDescriptor(variableName: String, value:String, label: String)`

I only found how to remove quotes around columns, not around each line.

Up to now I was using code like this:

```
    sparkSession
      .read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", ";")
      .csv("file.txt")
      .withColumnRenamed("VARIABLE", "variableName")
      .withColumnRenamed("MOD", "value")
      .withColumnRenamed("LIBMOD", "label")
      .as[ValueDescriptor]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first read it as text to drop the extra quotes

```
val txtDF = sparkSession
  .read
  .textFile("file.txt")
  .map(_.stripPrefix("\"").stripSuffix("\""))
```

and then load it as CSV

```
sparkSession
  .read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", ";")
  .csv(txtDF)
  .withColumnRenamed("VARIABLE", "variableName")
  .withColumnRenamed("MOD", "value")
  .withColumnRenamed("LIBMOD", "label")
  .as[ValueDescriptor]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it's so easy whereas I was trying spooky stuff using withColumns and functions!